# Opening ContextMenu from inside ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, android-arrayadapter

I have a `setOnClickLisnter` Method in my `getView` method in my Custom ArrayAdapter.

What I want to do is this, on a single, short click of an `imageButton` inside each row of the `ListView`, I want it to open up a ContextMenu.

I currently have the ContextMenu working when you long click on the `ListView`.  Now I want to move that same functionality over to the short click mentioned above.

I have this inside my `onCreate`:

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

I also have a `onCreateContextMenu` inside the Activity.  **My main question is, how do you access this from inside the `ArrayAdapter`?**

**EDIT:**  I don't have to do this inside a `setOncLickListner` method, just somewhere in the `getView`

Code of getView:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.commentlayout, parent,
                    false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ib1 = (ImageButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.labelChatIcon);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            convertView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(null);
        }

        holder.ib1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        holder.ib1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.ib1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Open Context Menu here

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

**UPDATE:  I think I am changing my plans and will use an Alert Dialog with Radio buttons.  A Context menu is probably no appropriate in this situation.**

Comment: How about sub-classing the ArrayAdapter so that it has an Activity attribute.  You pass it the activity reference(i.e. the activity reference) when you create the adapter.  Then you call the method on the activity.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I didn't think about doing it that way.  Right now, my `ArrayAdapter` is its own class.  For the moment, I'd like to see if there is a solution using this way first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an Alert.Builder instead of the context menu, you can add a custom view by using     `builder.setView(View v);`

You would have a layout file with a bunch of different buttons of width: match_parent. Check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) for all the different options available

Comment: Yeah but your edit said **EDIT: I don't have to do this inside a setOncLickListner method, just somewhere in the getView** But you do have to do it inside of the listener is all I was saying

Comment: The problem I believe is that context menus are predefined to be opened using a longclick. The best approach would probbaly be to use an alertBuilder instead with clickable options.

Comment: I have made Context Menus on short clicks before so I know that works... want to show me a more basic of a code example of what you mean then?

Comment: As far as the alertbuilder goes , you can add a custom view by adding using builder.setView(View v); You would have a layout file with a bunch of different buttons of width: match_parent. Check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) for all the different options available.

Comment: You know that's a great idea.  An Alert Dialog with multiple choice radio buttons would do exactly what I need here

Comment: Glad I could be of Service

Comment: If you want to edit your answer I will mark correct.  Can't really mark the current answer correct as it stands now...

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

and use

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit:
            editNote(info.id);
            return true;
        case R.id.delete:
            deleteNote(info.id);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This just shows me how to create the actual context menu which is not the question.  I need to know how to assign the action to a button inside an ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old but in case anybody else needs it:
You cannot open the context menu directly. However, you can perform a long click on the according view. This will open the context menu. In your case:

```
holder.ib1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Open Context Menu here
                convertView.performLongClick();
            }
        });
```

However, be aware that what you want is not according to Android's design guidelines. A long click is supposed to open the contextual menu, not a normal click.